# Angular 6 Depedency Injection (in module.ts)

Tags: angular

I have two different module in my app, and these modules have their own properties as usual.

So I want to register these two module into my another parent module, but these registration should take into consideration of my enviroment variable (which is created at my app run phase).

#### Example of my dependency injection

[image: Example of my dependency injection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer.

Actually the problem is, I don't know I can read my enviroment variable. I'm initializing my **APP_INITIALIZER** here in app.module.browser.ts,

```
  @NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppModuleShared,
    AppAuthModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER, // <-- HERE
      useFactory: configurationServiceFactory,
      deps: [ConfigurationService],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor, //AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
    ConfigurationService,
    ErrorLogService
  ]
```

After this initialization, I'm having some constant variables. I want to read my enviroment variable. So I can put this into **condition** as you said here.

```
let module: any = condition ? AccountsModule : AccountsPlusModule;
```